# Higher order moment estimation using the information of low order moments

Tags: random-variables, moment-generating-functions, moment-problem

Let $x \in \mathbb{R}$ be a random variable. Given the finite sequence of the moments, e.g., $E[x^{\alpha}], \alpha=0,..., N$, how we can obtain the higher order moments e.g., $E[x^{\alpha}], \alpha \geq N+1$.